# basic k way merge: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, array-merge

I am trying to implement basic merge k sorted array algorithm but with strings.
I am getting the following error.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
> what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

The code works fine if the `names` vector has just 2 sub vectors, but when I add another list in the `names` vector I am getting the above error.

Whats wrong with the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;



vector<string> merge_2_names(vector<string> a, vector<string> b){
    int i = 0 ; int j = 0;
    vector<string> res; 
    
    while(i < a.size() && j < b.size()){
        if (a[i].compare(b[j]) < 0){
            res.push_back(a[i]);
            i++;
        }else{
            res.push_back(b[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    
    while (i < a.size()){
        res.push_back(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    
    while(j < a.size()){
        res.push_back(b[j]);
        j++;
    }
    
    return res; 
}

vector<string> merge_k_names(vector<vector<string>> names){
    vector<string> result;
    
    cout << names.size() << "\n";
    
    for (string s: names[0]){
        result.push_back(s);
    }
    
    
    for(int i=1;i<names.size();i++) 
    { 
        result=merge_2_names(result,names[i]); 
    } 
    
    return result;
}

int main() {
    
    vector<vector<string>> names {{"adam" , "raja" , "zync"},
             {"edam" , "some" , "zian"},
             {"mike" , "jimm" , "pame"}};
             
    cout << names.size() << "\n";
             
    vector<string>  res = merge_k_names(names);
    
    for (string s: res){
        cout << s << " ";
    }
    
    return 0;
                            
}
```

Comment: `while(i < a.size()){` was used twice with `while(j < a.size()){`. Likely copy-paste error; you probably meant `while(j < b.size()){`. Recommend using valgrind or asan to catch these errors.

Comment: The program is hard coded for a 3 way merge. It needs to be updated to be a generic k way merge. Note that k-sorted refers to an array where no element is more than k elements from its sorted position. I updated the question's title to note this is a k way merge.